Python Accelerate package thrown error when using Trainer from Transformers
I'm trying out this Hugging Face tutorial
I'm trying to use a trainer to train my mode. The code errors out at this point:
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, DataCollatorWithPadding, TrainingArguments, Trainer

checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
raw_datasets = load_dataset("glue", "mrpc")

def tokenize_function(example):
    return tokenizer(example["sentence1"], example["sentence2"], truncation=True)

tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)

data_collator = DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer)

training_args = TrainingArguments("test-trainer")

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(checkpoint, num_labels=2)

#The above code works upto here
#The following line fails
trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"], 
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
)

The error is displayed as:
File "tutorial.py", line 21, in <module>
    trainer = Trainer(
              ^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py3env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 388, in __init__
    self.create_accelerator_and_postprocess()
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/py3env/lib/python3.12/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 4364, in create_accelerator_and_postprocess
    self.accelerator = Accelerator(**args)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Accelerator.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_seedable_sampler'

Versions:
Python: 3.12.3
Transformer: 4.40.2
Datasets: 2.19.1
Accelerate: 0.21.0


Seems like you have to force update Accelerate with the specific version 0.30.0.
Simply installing 'accelerate' won't work,
$ conda install accelerate

....as it will pick the latest to be 0.21.0 as listed below,
$ conda search accelerate
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
huggingface_accelerate          0.20.3 py310hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
huggingface_accelerate          0.20.3 py311hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
huggingface_accelerate          0.20.3  py38hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
huggingface_accelerate          0.20.3  py39hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
huggingface_accelerate          0.21.0 py310hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
huggingface_accelerate          0.21.0 py311hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
huggingface_accelerate          0.21.0 py312hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
huggingface_accelerate          0.21.0  py38hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
huggingface_accelerate          0.21.0  py39hca03da5_0  pkgs/main           
pyopengl-accelerate            3.1.5  py38heec5a64_0  pkgs/main           
pyopengl-accelerate            3.1.5  py39heec5a64_0  pkgs/main  

You will have to force install 0.30.0 by specifying it as the version,
$ conda install accelerate=0.30.0


"pip install accelerate==0.27.2" resolved this issue on my end.
Ref: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/29216
